# Child Themes and Updating Parent Theme

Tags: plugins, child-theme, updates

I have not got a child theme set up for the theme I'm using, though there is an update for the theme now. I've had a google and they say that if you don't have a child theme you will loose your "customisation".

When they say customisation are they referring to any code you've altered? As I haven't altered any.
Or are they referring to any content, posts, pictures, changes to the home page you've made (through the customise UI in the appearance section).

If it does refer to the content, posts etc. is there any easy plugin or other way of easily restoring that to the updated theme, without having to go through setting up a child theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are referring to the source PHP, JavaScript, and CSS and really any other files contained within the parent theme's directory. If you have not modified the files within the parent theme, you shouldn't have much to worry about. Your posts, pages, and other content should not be deleted from updating a theme.

It is possible that the updated theme will handle features in different or unexpected ways. You should still back up your site's database and files prior to doing an update as a precaution.